# How do I customize the display of edge labels in networkx?

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I create a graph with edge attributions (say `r`, such as, `r=23`).

How do display edge labels only with the values, `23` instead of `{'r':'23'}`.

[image]

Related source codes are below:

```
# build a graph
G.add_edge(u, v, r=value)

# plot the graph
pos = nx.spring_layout(G, scale=2)

nx.draw(G, pos)

edge_labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'r')
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, labels = edge_labels)

plt.savefig(out_file)
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The command `draw_networkx_edge_labels` needs the argument `edge_labels` rather than `labels`.

So you need to change `nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, labels = edge_labels)` to `nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels = edge_labels)`

Comment: @rschwieb : I would ask a separate question, with a [mcve]

Answer (score 3):

This way it worked on my :

```py
grafo_labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'weight')

edges_label = nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels = grafo_labels)
```