# Draw edge with weight dataframe (networkx)

Tags: python, networkx

I would like to draw every edge between each name according to weight, i tried :

```
plt.figure(figsize=(35,35))

options = {
    'edge_color': '#eebcbc',
    'width': 1,
    'with_labels': True,
    'font_weight': 'regular',
}

G   = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(bin_nom, "structure" , "Prénom", 
                              edge_attr= [col for col in bin_nom["Prénom"]] ,
                              create_using=nx.Graph())

d = dict(G.degree)

nx.draw(G, pos=nx.spring_layout(G, k=0.85, iterations=100),
        node_color='blue', 
        nodelist=d.keys(), node_size=[v * 100 for v in d.values()], 
       **options)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.collections[0].set_edgecolor("#000007") 
plt.show()
```

it give me

[image: network]

My weight matrix is a pandas dataframe with name as col and name as index like that

[image: weight dataframe]

Comment: Do you mean you want the weight of the edges as label of the edges in the graph?

Comment: Each name has a score between 0 and 3 with other name which represent the link between two person 0 i would like to draw a line that join every people to his relation and thé must would be to put the strength of link as a label of Line

Comment: Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47094949/labeling-edges-in-networkx?