# Is there a way to show number of connection between nodes and edges in networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I have bidirectional graph in networkx and I would like to show how many connections are there between two nodes.
As show in picture I would like to add two numbers (or at least one) which show how many connections are between two nodes. Graph is more complicated than this since this is example problem.

[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5hpa.png)

Update:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'from': fromlist, 'to': tolist})
 G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'from', 'to', create_using=nx.DiGraph())
 if.self.ui.radioButtonCircular.isChecked():
      nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, node_size=5500, node_color=[mapper.to_rgba(i)
      for i in d.values()], font_size=7, node_shape="s", alpha=0.7, arrows=True,
      pos=nx.circular_layout(G))
 plt.title("Directed")
 plt.show()
```

There is a lot of analysis above this, but in my fromlist and tolist are connections. Something like this:

```
fromlist: A, A, A, B, B, A, C
tolist:   B, C, B, A, A, B, A
```

Now I would like it to show me in biderectional graph that A is connected with B three times, that B is connected with A 2 times, that C is connnected with A once, but A is connected with C also one time,... Is this possible in networkx?

Comment: Can you show your code so far? Or at least a simplified example?

Comment: @motrix I updated my question with code that draws... I have a lot of analysis before this, but in my fromlist and tolist are connections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DiGraphs don't allow parallel edges as stated in https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/digraph.html.

So if you do `print(G['A']['B'])` only one edge shows.

Maybe you can try assigning an attribute to the edge, for example:

```
for from_node, to_node in zip(from_list, to_list):
    if G.has_edge(from_node, to_node):
        G[from_node][to_node]['count'] += 1
    else:
        G.add_edge(from_node, to_node, count = 1)
```

Then you can show the edge atrributes as shown in [Labeling edges in networkx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47094949/labeling-edges-in-networkx#62892781)

If your graph is very large and the for loop takes too much time you can do:

```
df['count'] = 1
df = df.groupby(['from', 'to']).sum().reset_index()
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'from', 'to', ['count'], create_using=nx.DiGraph())
```